# Why does bootstrap modal close event "stack"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a confirmation control which could be added multiple times to the page, however I stumbled upon this error which caused these controls to "touch" one another (obviously I want to make them work independently).

I am using Bootstrap for this and as little as possible jQuery (due to debugging).

After some slicing, I found out that within my code, the Bootstrap close function will be run multiple times causing this issue. Would anyone happen to know why this Bootstrap function is run multiple times?

This would be the **cause** of my problem:

```
$("").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  //Why does this stack?
  alert("Why does this stack?");
});
```

This is the **context** of my code where it will be run multiple times:

```js
//Yes selector
const positiveSelector = ".positive";
//No selector
const negativeSelector = ".negative";
//Confirm? selector
const confirmSelector = ".init-confirm"
//Pending selector
const pendingSelector = ".pending";
//Yes ele
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector);
//No ele
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector);
//Confirm? ele
const confirmNodes = document.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector);
//Pending ele
const pendingNodes = document.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector);

//Modal related:
const $modalInit = $(".modal").html();
const targetModal = $("#bs-modal-xl");

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-success");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.removeAttribute("disabled"));
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-warning");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "none");
}));

confirmNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let thisNode = this;

  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "inline-block");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-danger"));
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Pending");

  //Populate modal:
  ModalHandler($(".my-ele").clone(), "My ele", undefined, true, true);
  $(".modal .my-ele").show();
  //Show Modal:
  targetModal.modal();

  $(".modal").on("click", ".my-ele button", function () {
    targetModal.modal("hide");
  });

  //When closing Modal:
  targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    //Why does this stack?
    alert("Why does this stack?");
  });
}));


//Modal handling (not required when not using Modal):
function ModalHandler(content, title, footer = "", bigCloseBtn = false, emptyFooter = false) {
  $(".modal h4.modal-title").text(title);
  $(".modal .modal-body").html(content);

  if (footer != "" && footer != undefined) {
    $(".modal .modal-footer").html(footer);
  }

  if (bigCloseBtn) {
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").css("float", "right");
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").addClass("btn btn-lg btn-danger");
    //$(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").html("close");
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").removeClass("close");
  }

  if (emptyFooter) {
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  }
}

$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  $(".modal").html($modalInit);
});
```

```css
#foo-container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.pending {
  display: none;
}

.my-ele {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="foo-container">
  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
  </div>
  
  <br />

  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-ele">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Clicky</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2q6k1os/)

In order to **reproduce** my problem, the modal has to be opened by clicking on the "Yes" button to enable the "Confirm?" button and click this button. Then exit out of the modal. The event will be run over one time, however when repeating the opening and closing of the modal, the alerts start stacking (due to the fact the events start stacking up for some reason, which I do not understand).

The reason I have the

`.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {});` within the `eventListener`

of any

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>`

is because I need to pass the clicked element as parameter to an external function.

Could I make the modal close function run only a single time instead of "getting these stacked"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the event is applied over and over again on `targetModal.on`. You need to turn it `off`.

```
targetModal.off();
```

```js
//Yes selector
const positiveSelector = ".positive";
//No selector
const negativeSelector = ".negative";
//Confirm? selector
const confirmSelector = ".init-confirm"
//Pending selector
const pendingSelector = ".pending";
//Yes ele
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector);
//No ele
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector);
//Confirm? ele
const confirmNodes = document.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector);
//Pending ele
const pendingNodes = document.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector);

//Modal related:
const $modalInit = $(".modal").html();
const targetModal = $("#bs-modal-xl");

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-success");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.removeAttribute("disabled"));
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-warning");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
  thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "none");
}));

confirmNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let thisNode = this;

  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "inline-block");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-danger"));
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Pending");

  //Populate modal:
  ModalHandler($(".my-ele").clone(), "My ele", undefined, true, true);
  $(".modal .my-ele").show();
  //Show Modal:
  targetModal.modal();

  $(".modal").on("click", ".my-ele button", function() {
    targetModal.modal("hide");
  });

  //When closing Modal:
  targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
    //Why does this stack?
    alert("Why does this stack?");
    targetModal.off();
  });
}));


//Modal handling (not required when not using Modal):
function ModalHandler(content, title, footer = "", bigCloseBtn = false, emptyFooter = false) {
  $(".modal h4.modal-title").text(title);
  $(".modal .modal-body").html(content);

  if (footer != "" && footer != undefined) {
    $(".modal .modal-footer").html(footer);
  }

  if (bigCloseBtn) {
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").css("float", "right");
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").addClass("btn btn-lg btn-danger");
    //$(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").html("close");
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").removeClass("close");
  }

  if (emptyFooter) {
    $(".modal .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  }
}

$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  $(".modal").html($modalInit);
});
```

```css
#foo-container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.pending {
  display: none;
}

.my-ele {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="foo-container">
  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-ele">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Clicky</button>
</div>
```